# Как получить высоту экрана Android?

Tags: java, android

В своем приложении в зависимости от разрешения экрана я масштабирую элементы интерфейса. В методе `OnCreate` я получаю высоту и ширину в пикселях из `DisplayMetrics` и провожу вычисления. Этот способ работает только на телефоне без навигационной панели снизу, а там, где она есть, высота экрана обрезается. Приложение работает на полный экран, поэтому нужно получить высоту всего экрана.

Есть ли способ узнать **полную** высоту экрана?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Лучше используйте ConstraintLayout и GuideLine, позволит настроить масштаб View-шек, в процентном соотношении, крайне удобная вещь.

Comment: Там же всё автоматически пож размер экрана меняется, иди вы жёстко задаёте размеры? Это не совсем правильно